# Округляется число типа double

Tags: c#

Есть число

```
double test = 0;
```

При некоторых условиях оно меняется

```
test = json.test;
```

`json.test` -- элемент из json массива типа double. В нём хранится число 9.5

Затем я через GET отправляю `test` в php файл, где оно записывается в БД. 
У меня записывается в базу число 9. В чём может быть причина?
В php никакого округления нет

Проблема иногда появляется, иногда исчезает.

Так сделал, чтобы не нужно было конвертировать числа перед отправкой в PHP файл

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
}
```

Comment: А вот условия проходит
`if(json.test == 9.5)`

Comment: Вы не предоставили кода в котором проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.double.compareto?view=netframework-4.8) ты можешь найти ответ.
Как вариант:

> Значения должны быть одинаковыми, чтобы считаться равными. Особенно если значения с плавающей запятой зависят от нескольких математических операций, обычно они теряют точность и их значения практически идентичны, за исключением их наименьших значащих цифр. По этой причине возвращаемое значение метода CompareTo в некоторых случаях может показаться неудивительной. Например, умножение на определенное значение, за которым следует деление на одно и то же значение, должно создать исходное значение. Однако в следующем примере вычисленное значение оказывается больше, чем исходное значение.

Или, другими словами, не нужно использовать вещественные числа для сравнения от слова совсем. В программировании это значение, которое говорит о примерной величине. Если нужно оперировать точностью - используй соответствующие объекты. В финансах например BigDecimal (Java). Про аналог в шарпе можно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523741/arbitrary-precision-decimals-in-c-sharp) почитать.